# iOS UINavigation "Back" button Bezier Path

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibezierpath

In my app I have custom gradients I use to stylize all instances of `UIBarButtonItem`, accomplished by creating a gradient, clipping the gradient with a rounded rectangle Bezier path, then creating a resizable UIImage, like so:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
CGSize size = rect.size;
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
size_t gradientNumberOfLocations = 2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef btncontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat btngradientLocations[2] = { 0.2, 1.0 };
CGFloat btngradientComponents[8] = { 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 1.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 1.0 };

CGGradientRef btngradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorspace, btngradientComponents, btngradientLocations, gradientNumberOfLocations);

UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:4.0f];
[path addClip];

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(btncontext, btngradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, size.height), 0);

UIImage *btnimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGGradientRelease(btngradient);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

UIImage *navButton = [btnimage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(22.0, 8.0, 22.0, 8.0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works just fine, and I am developing a similar method to stylize the back button via `-setBackButtonBackgroundImage`, however I have a question:

I would like to know if anyone has knows a proper way to create a `UIBezierPath` object that represents the outline of the back button, such that I can create a gradient and programmatically clip the gradient to a back button shape (just like in the example) without having to use a PNG or some such resource.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Took me a while to find this, but here's a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993328/create-the-indented-look-found-in-uinavigationbarbutton-programmatically